# Why does calloc require two parameters and malloc just one?

Tags: c, memory-management

It's very bothersome for me to write `calloc(1, sizeof(MyStruct))` all the time. I don't want to use an idea like wrapping this method and etc. I mean I want to know what two parameters gives me? If it gives something, why doesn't `malloc`have two parameters too?

By the way, I searched for an answer to this question but I didn't find a really good answer. Those answers was that `calloc` can allocate larger blocks than `malloc` can and etc.

I saw another answer that `calloc` allocates an array. With `malloc` I can multiply and I'll get an array and I can use it without `1,` at the start.

Comment: Because `calloc` allocate a zeroed array of elements of the same size, while `malloc` allocate an uninitialized heap zone.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4083916/two-arguments-to-calloc

Comment: @gtgaxiola I saw that answer. It's with the larger blocks. It's not what I asked for :(.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch That's no reason for two parameters, a simple size in bytes (like malloc) would be enough to zero the memory.

Comment: This is a duplicate question that has been asked several times before, e.g., http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4083916/two-arguments-to-calloc and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7581192/how-did-malloc-and-calloc-end-up-with-different-signatures

Comment: @JimBalter Those questions didn't got really answer. (Read all of the text of the question)

Comment: @DividedByZero The fact that you didn't find what you consider a good answer doesn't change the fact that the questions are duplicates.

Comment: @JimBalter When there is no good version for something ,we making new and a better version and replace it with that something.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Historical reasons.

At the time of when `calloc` was introduced, the `malloc` function didn't exist and the `calloc` function would provide the correct alignment for one element object.

When `malloc` was introduced afterwards, it was decided the memory returned would be properly aligned for any use (which costs more memory) and so only one parameter was necessary. The API for `calloc` was not changed but `calloc` now also returns memory properly aligned for any use.

**EDIT:**

See the discussion in the comments and the interesting input from [@JimBalter](https://stackoverflow.com/users/544557/jim-balter).

My first statement regarding the introduction of `malloc` and `calloc` may be totally wrong.

Also the real reasons could also be well unrelated to alignment. C history has been changed a lot by compiler implementers. `malloc` and `calloc` could come from different groups / compilers implementers and this would explain the API difference. And I actually favor this explanation as the real reason.

Comment: +1 - Wow, answers a question that always burnt in my soul with a (more or less) reasonable explanation. I also didn't know `calloc` was older than `malloc`, as `malloc` seems the more fundamental thing.

Comment: Can you please cite a reference for the claim that calloc preceded malloc? I've been programming in C since Bell Labs Unix version 6, and I'm almost certain that this claim is incorrect.

Comment: @JimBalter There is an explanation in clc in https://groups.google.com/d/msg/comp.lang.c/jZbiyuYqjB4/NIAmeNd11IoJ  The poster quotes a paragraph of K&R1 about `calloc` function. The K&R1 paragraph also mentions the existence of an `alloc` function.

Comment: Your source is wrong; malloc existed long before K&R1 was written in 1978. The alloc function was *pedagogy*, existing only for the sake of explanation in the book; there was never such a function in the C library.

Comment: @JimBalter Do you have a copy of K&R1? From the source `malloc` was not specified in K&R1. Note that for the `alloc` function I agree you are probably right, there is also an `alloc` example in K&R2.

Comment: What I have is an apparently faulty memory ... but it's still more accurate than your source. From http://man.cat-v.org/unix-6th/3/ we can see that `alloc` and `free` were in the library, but not `calloc`, and `alloc` only took one argument. Again, K&R1 was *pedagogical*, and was about the C language, not a reference manual for UNIX or the C library. calloc, with its two arguments, was added to UNIX in the Programmer's Workbench (PWB), which came between V6 and V7 (and later became System III), and was found in V7: http://plan9.bell-labs.com/7thEdMan/vol1/man3.bun

Comment: @JimBalter thank you for the interesting links. I still think the reasons for the API difference between malloc and calloc is because of alignment. I could not see any other valid reasons. Do you have another opinon?

Comment: I think the main reason for the difference is that they were designed by different groups. PWB was developed by a group at Bell Labs separate from research, and that introduced some redundancy into the library and the commands. I don't think alignment buys much since the length (or a pointer to the next block) was stored with the allocated memory and it would be painful to manipulate it if it wasn't aligned -- and portability meant that alignment requirement was loose.

Comment: +1 Nice. We don't really know, and it's good to acknowledge that. I'm almost inclined to delete my strongly stated but false comment that alloc was never part of the library, but I think I'll leave it, humbled by how sure I was of something that isn't true.

Comment: @JimBalter I also wanted to delete my answer but I think it is better if the discussion remains.

Comment: Another small part of the story is the existence of `cfree` (http://linux.die.net/man/3/cfree).

Comment: @JimBalter: interesting - the existence of `cfree()` suggests that `calloc()` did not store the metadata about block size...

Comment: Look at http://minnie.tuhs.org/cgi-bin/utree.pl and search for alloc and marvel at what you will discover ... e.g., http://minnie.tuhs.org/cgi-bin/utree.pl?file=V7M/src/libc/gen/calloc.c ("gen" was the PWB library that was an addendum to the C library).

Answer (score 5):

The only reason I could come up with is that

```
int *foo = calloc(42, sizeof *foo);
```

is one character shorter than

```
int *foo = malloc(42 * sizeof *foo);
```

The real reason is apparently lost to the <del>millennia</del> <del>centuries</del> decades of C history and needs a programming language archaeologist to unearth, but might be related to the following fact:

In contrast to `malloc()` - which needs to return a memory block aligned in accordance to the full block size - when using `calloc()` as intended, the memory block would only need to be aligned in accordance to the size passed as second argument. However, the C standard forbids this optimization in conforming implementations.

Comment: It's just to allocate memory ,it can't optimize it. If it can then it can optimize it both the allocate methods.

Comment: @DividedByZero: say your architectures supports 2-byte and 4-byte alignment; `malloc(6)` will need to return a 4-byte aligned block, whereas `calloc(3, 2)` could return a 2-byte aligned block if not for the restrictions probably introduced when C was standardized

Comment: The C standard (I was on the standards committee, so this one I remember well) came long after malloc and calloc were introduced. And I'm pretty sure that, as of UNIX Version 7, calloc just called malloc and then cleared the memory.

Comment: @JimBalter: thanks for your clarification; from the link you provided in another comment, it appears that there existed \*nixes where one had to call `cfree()` on blocks allocated via `calloc()` - so at least *someone* needed to come up with the semantics which were later incorporated into the standard; I wouldn't be surprised if this actually happened due to laziness when porting `calloc()` to another *nix variant

Comment: Search for alloc at http://minnie.tuhs.org/cgi-bin/utree.pl and you'll discover a lot of interesting things, like http://minnie.tuhs.org/cgi-bin/utree.pl?file=V6/usr/source/iolib/calloc.c

Answer (score 0):

it is just by design.

you could write your own calloc

```
void *mycalloc(size_t num, size_t size)
{
    void *block = malloc(num * size);
    if(block != NULL)
        memset(block, 0, num * size);
    return block;
}
```

Comment: Why was this correct answer downvoted without comment? Such downvotes are bad SO citizenry.

Comment: @JimBalter Design is not an answer. Programming is not an iPhone and who create this function'll not has a time on designing his functions.

Comment: @GamecatisToonKrijthe I don't know what your comment means. Answers at SO initially have a vote of 0, and there's an answer below with no downvotes, and an answer above with 2 downvotes. None of the downvotes have been explained nor have the downvoters taken responsibility.

Comment: @DividedByZero I can't parse your comment, which is not in English. iPhones aren't the only thing designed; programs and APIs are also designed. The answer is correct: one or two arguments is a design choice, nothing more.

Comment: @JimBalter I mean like adding parameters to it and make it more beautiful. The second parameter is useless and annoying.

Comment: @DividedByZero that's not what "design" means in programming. And there is no reason to think that there are two parameters to "make it more beautiful".

Comment: This calloc is buggy, it's easily vulnerable to overflow.

Answer (score -2):

You shouldn't allocate objects with calloc (or malloc or anything like that). Even though calloc zero-initializes it, the object is still hasn't been constructed as far as C++ is concerned. Use constructors for that:

```
class MyClass
{
private:
    short m_a;
    int m_b;
    long m_c;
    float m_d;

public:
    MyClass() : m_a(0), m_b(0), m_c(0), m_d(0.0) {}
};
```

And then instantiate it with `new` (or on the stack if you can):

```
MyClass* mc = new MyClass();
```

Comment: This question is about C not C++.

Comment: But you said that you were writing `calloc(1, sizeof(MyClass))`, which suggests you're using calloc to allocate objects. If not, what is MyClass then?

Comment: One can do class-oriented programming in C and define things like `typedef struct { /* instance variables */ } MyClass;`

Comment: @JimBalter That would be a struct (a POD more precisely), not a class in the object-oriented sense. I guess we'll have to hear it from DividedByZero.

Comment: @user1610015 It is a class in the object-oriented sense if it is accompanied by functions like `MyClass_foo(MyClass* this, ...)`. "object-oriented" is a methodology, not a syntax.

Comment: @JimBalter It may be accompanied by functions, but MyClass still isn't a class because it has no encapsulation and no behavior, just POD (Plain Old Data).

Comment: @user1610015 It doesn't have to have those things to be object-oriented, or to be a class ... but those functions *are* behavior, and encapsulation is achieved by the naming convention. Again, it's about methodology, not syntax. POD is a C++ term, but C++ is not the only arbiter of what "object-oriented" or "class" mean. Anyway, we're way off topic, and I'm done.