# how malloc() can be used to create a dynamic array if it allocates only one block of memory which can be stored for only one variable?

Tags: c, dynamic-arrays

`malloc()` function creates a whole block of memory and then return the pointer of the first byte. If it creates only one block of memory, then it can only store only one element right? But how `malloc()` stores multiple elements in only one block of memory whereas it makes sense when  `calloc()` creates multiple blocks of memory and it can be used as an dynamic array.

Comment: Both just allocate a block of memory and it’s up to you what you do with them. Think of it this way: you ask for 20 pieces of paper. Does it matter if they are given as one stack of 20 or five stacks of four on top of each other? Does it change what you can write or draw on them? The same with memory. It’s just a bunch of bytes.

Comment: You are missing the 3rd leg of the 3-legged stool -- `realloc`. Yes `malloc/calloc` allocate a single block of memory, but when that block gets full, you call `realloc` and increase the size of the block and copy the existing content to the new block of memory. (that's what `realloc` does). So you can allocate some initial block and then `realloc` as needed to grow (or shrink).

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4083916/two-arguments-to-calloc

Comment: `char x[5];` is another example of a single block of storage that can contain multiple values

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is bread and butter allocated memory management. It works the same way no matter what type of data you are allocating/reallocating for. The three standard functions provided for dynamic memory allocation are `malloc/calloc/realloc`. While `malloc/calloc` are limited to allocating a single block of memory, `realloc` can also *resize* a block of memory allowing you to allocate some initial block of storage with `malloc/calloc` (or you can do it with `realloc`) and then use `realloc` to increase or decrease the amount of memory allocated.

As with every function call where you allocate memory, you must validate the call succeeds by checking that the return is not `NULL`. This is why when using `realloc` you *always `realloc` with a temporary pointer!*. So when (not if) `realloc` fails because you have run out of memory, you do not overwrite your original pointer with `NULL` losing the address for the block of memory and creating a memory leak.

For example if you have allocated for `int *block = malloc (...)`, you do NOT `realloc` as:

```
block = realloc (block, 2 * n * sizeof *block);    /* to double size */
```

If `realloc` fails -- what is returned, and what does `block` now hold? (hint: `NULL`). So instead, you use a temporary pointer, e.g.

```
/* always realloc to a temp pointer, or risk losing pointer */
void *tmp = realloc (block, 2 * n * sizeof *block);   /* doubling size */
if (!tmp) {         /* validate every allocation */
    perror ("realloc-block");
    /* handle error - original pointer still good */
}
block = tmp;        /* assign reallocated block */
```

(**note:** the use of `void *tmp` is done because that is the return type for `realloc`. It could just a validly be `int *tmp` to match the type for `block`. The key is your temporary pointer `tmp` must be type compatible with `block` for the assignment of the reallocated block, e.g. `block = tmp;`. For new C programmers, in C any pointer can be cast to/from `void*` without an explicit cast. So `void *tmp` is just a generic temporary type to use, but the type for `block` would be every bit as correct there)

That way you do not assign the reallocated block until you have **validated** the call to `realloc` succeeded. You can increase by any number you like. Doubling is fine, or just adding some fixed number is fine, etc..

The scheme to handle reallocating anything is straight-forward. You allocate a block to hold some number of objects. You keep a counter of the number allocated (say `alloced`). Then you keep a separate counter of the number of objects used (say `used`). Then before using the memory for another object if filling in a loop, etc. you simply check if `used == alloced`, e.g.:

```
if (used == alloced) {          /* check if realloc needed */
    /* realloc here */
    alloced *= 2;               /* update no. allocated (doubling size here) */
}
```

You reallocate and then update your `alloced` counter to the new size, and keep on going...

A short example initially allocating for `2` integers and then reallocating as needed by doubling the current allocation size to read and store and unlimited number of integers is a basic example. As mentioned above, you can increase the allocation size by whatever you like, but avoid reallocating for every addition. Memory allocation is a relatively expensive call. So doubling, e.g. growing the allocation from storage for `2` to storage for `4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128, ...` is a reasonable growth rate that avoids repeated unnecessary reallocation as objects are added.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAXI 2                  /* initial number of integer to allocate */

int main (void) {

    size_t  alloced = MAXI,     /* counter to track number allocate */
            used = 0;           /* counter to track number used */
    int val = 0,                /* value to read from stdin */
        *block = malloc (alloced * sizeof *block);  /* initial allocation */

    if (!block) {   /* validate every allocation */
        perror ("malloc-block");
        return 1;
    }

    while (scanf ("%d", &val) == 1) {   /* while integer read */
        if (used == alloced) {          /* check if realloc needed */
            /* always realloc to a temp pointer, or risk losing pointer */
            void *tmp = realloc (block, 2 * alloced * sizeof *block);
            if (!tmp) {         /* validate every allocation */
                perror ("realloc-block");
                if (!used)      /* if no ints stored, exit */
                    return 1;
                break;          /* otherwise original pointer still good */
            }
            block = tmp;        /* assign reallocated block */
            alloced *= 2;       /* update no. of ints allocated */
        }
        block[used++] = val;    /* add value to block and update used */
    }

    printf ("no. of bytes allocated : %zu\n"
            "no. of bytes used      : %zu\n"
            "no. of ints stored     : %zu\n",
            alloced * sizeof *block, used * sizeof *block , used);

    free (block);   /* don't forget to free what you allocate */
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

We initially allocated for `2-int`, so lets try reading `100000` and see how it goes...

```
$ ./bin/malloc_realloc < ../dat/100000int.txt
no. of bytes allocated : 524288
no. of bytes used      : 400000
no. of ints stored     : 100000
```

So you can see we have over-allocated on our last `realloc` by `124288-bytes`. Not bad, but since you know the number of ints used, you can `realloc` a final time to size the block to hold exactly `100000-int` by:

```
void *tmp = realloc (block, used * sizeof *block);
...
```

(that is left to you to experiment with -- but you cannot `realloc` to a size less than the number of stored values)

**Memory Use/Error Check**

In any code you write that dynamically allocates memory, you have 2 *responsibilities* regarding any block of memory allocated: (1) *always preserve a pointer to the starting address* for the block of memory so, (2) it can be *freed* when it is no longer needed.

It is imperative that you use a memory error checking program to insure you do not attempt to access memory or write beyond/outside the bounds of your allocated block, attempt to read or base a conditional jump on an uninitialized value, and finally, to confirm that you free all the memory you have allocated.

For Linux `valgrind` is the normal choice. There are similar memory checkers for every platform. They are all simple to use, just run your program through it.

```
$ valgrind ./bin/malloc_realloc < ../dat/100000int.txt
==28169== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==28169== Copyright (C) 2002-2015, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==28169== Using Valgrind-3.12.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==28169== Command: ./bin/malloc_realloc
==28169==
no. of bytes allocated : 524288
no. of bytes used      : 400000
no. of ints stored     : 100000
==28169==
==28169== HEAP SUMMARY:
==28169==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==28169==   total heap usage: 17 allocs, 17 frees, 1,048,568 bytes allocated
==28169==
==28169== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==28169==
==28169== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==28169== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

(**note:** the `1,048,568` bytes allocated above is the sum of `2 * sizeof(int), 4 * sizeof(int), ....`)

Always confirm that you have freed all memory you have allocated and that there are no memory errors.

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.

If you want to check the total allocation adds up, you can do that from your shell (presuming POSIX shell) with a `for` loop and the POSIX mathematics operator, e.g.

```
sum=0; for i in $(seq 1 17); do sum=$((sum + (1 << i) * 4)); done; echo $sum
1048568
```

Comment: That was a perfect explanation I needed.

Comment: You are very welcome. We all had to learn it at one time, and it sure helps if somebody can break it down and make it easy to understand. All coding is that way. (there is just a lot of it to learn, so don't rush, it's not a race). Good luck with your coding!

Comment: I'm a student . If you don't mind, can you give me your personal social id like whatsapp, insta etc:- to message you incase if i have any doubts. Thanks very much

Comment: cuz I don't find a way to message you in stack overflow as there's no such option

Comment: No problem, but I"m an old digital hermit. I'm not a bird, I don't tweet, I probably couldn't find whatsapp if my life depended on it, etc.. But drop a comment and I'm glad to help further. gmail or github, there is only one drankinatty.

Comment: my mail id is allan05082000@gmail.com  . Mail me ..if you don't want your mail id to be shown in the comments. Thanks you once again

Comment: (hint: above "gmail or github, there is only one *drankinatty*" `:)`

Comment: Why are you using `void *` ?

Comment: Umm, because that's what `realloc` returns? No reason in particular other than that. Could just as well have been `int *`, but just a habit I guess. (but very good thought prompting -- probably should have explained that -- comment), Thanks @EdHeal

Comment: I would think `int *` would be better. i.e. for its intended use.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it takes `only one block` but this one block can be divide in an infinite block too depending on the required size you're asking for.

Answer (score 0):

The way I understand it, `malloc()` allocates one *block* of memory, but it is guaranteed to be contiguous. And an array is just a pointer to the first element of contiguous memory (it is up to the programmer to keep track of the size of the array). Note that this is the same thing as the output of `malloc()`. The one *block* of memory can contain as many elements as you want, just as long as you created a big enough block for the desired number of elements. `calloc()` does exactly the same thing, but initializes the block to all zeros, so that makes it a little more convenient for initializing an array.