# Is there any specific difference between calloc calls of equivalent length but different per-object size?

Tags: c, calloc

```
// Is

calloc(10, 5);

// exactly the same as 

calloc(50, 1);
calloc(25, 2);
```

etc. in all possible cases?

Comment: There is a point in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19021875/298225) that `calloc(x, y)` gives the C implementation an opportunity to test for overflow and return a null pointer if the allocation cannot be granted, whereas, if `x`•`y` is too large, `malloc(x*y)` would either have undefined behavior (if `x` and `y` are signed) or allocate less memory than desired.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can imagine that `calloc(m, n)` is 100% completely and totally equivalent to

```
p = malloc(m * n);
if(p) memset(p, 0, m*n);
```

There are various questions that come up with respect to alignment, but the answer is "no, `calloc` doesn't do anything special -- that is, doesn't do anything different than plain `malloc` -- with respect to alignment".

There are obviously problems if `m*n` is too big to allocate (or too big for type `size_t` to represent), but if you're trying to allocate that much, pretty much all bets are off.  (But with that said, if `m*n` is large enough to make `calloc` fail, I suspect the results could be noticeably different, and might even be *required* by the Standard to be noticeably different, from the simplified code given here.)

Finally, the zeroing done by `calloc` definitely *is* to all-bits-0, just like `memset`, which may have implications for initialized pointers or floating-point quantities on some architectures.

See also the [C FAQ](http://c-faq.com) list, [question 7.31](http://c-faq.com/malloc/calloc.html).